# Android OpenGL-ES texture is displayed messed up

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures

I made a small function that iterates over a string and puts new texture coordinates in a buffer according to the coordinates of each character in the 256x256 font texture, so I can render the text with OpenGL vertex arrays.

```
private void updateTexCoords()
    {
        float unit = 0.0625f;
        byte[] arr = string.getBytes();
        for(int i = 0; i < string.length()*8; i += 8)
        {
            float x = (float)(((int)arr[i/8] & 0xff)%16)*unit;
            float y = (float)(((int)arr[i/8] & 0xff)/16)*unit;
            //axis center is at (0,1) pointing right, down
            texture[0+i] = x; texture[1+i] = y+unit; //bottom left
            texture[2+i] = x; texture[3+i] = y; //top left
            texture[4+i] = x+unit; texture[5+i] = y+unit; //bottom right
            texture[6+i] = x+unit; texture[7+i] = y; //top right
        }
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);
    }
```

It works excellent for all of the devices tested on except one old phone, HTC nexus one,
where it shows messed up symbols although there is a pattern and you see that basically the texture coordinates given to it are somehow wrong. 
What could cause such a problem on one specific device, especially when working in Java and not messing with the native hardware-related things?

Answer (score 1):

Some Android devices simply have buggy OpenGL ES drivers.  HTC might have updated drivers available.  Which GPU type is it?  If it works correctly on the AVD emulation, then your code is probably fine.

If you are using backface culling, I would also try reversing the winding direction that is culled.

Comment: All of the images except text are shown correctly. Even those that have custom texture coordinates (not the standard 0f and 1f).